# Android and using Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: email

I would like to sync my THUNDERBIRD program on my PC to my GALAXY NOTE 2, is this possible as the web suggests it is possible

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird is not an email service, it is an email client. Therefore it accesses an email service from the internet. If you have an email client on your phone, or use an online one, as long as they are both accessing the same email service they will be synchronized. It's probably better to use IMAP as it works better for synchronizing multiple clients.

Comment: ...assuming IMAP is used as protocol (with POP, when messages are downloaded from the server they are by default deleted on the server, so the second client wouldn't see them. Furthermore, with POP it's hard to sync the read state).

Comment: Does that mean if I install outlook with the same settings as my Thunderbird I can sync accounts

Comment: @Izzy Good point; I'll add that to my answer. Stebar: The settings may be different for different clients; check with your email provider to see which settings to use for each.

Comment: Okay what does someone recommend to run with Thunderbird so I can get my email on the move

Comment: This is for a work account and therefore I cannot use Yahoo

Comment: @stebar Just google "free email android app" and you'll find several.

Comment: Why not add an email forwarding account on your yahoo email setting, to your gmail, and use it in this fashion? And from your Galaxy Note, still use Gmail app.

Comment: Or look for *k-9 mail* in the playstore, and handle different providers from within one app (I wouldn't like to trust one provider with all my data either :)

Comment: Are there any people who can get their mails from their PC´s and mobile,K9 looks poor, this can not be a difficult issue, surely